# Probability in lotteries

Tags: probability

In place where I live, there is a very popular lottery, with these simple rules: there is a list of numbers from 1 to 49, and the player chooses 6 out of them. If all of them are guessed, then the price is awarded. It's simple to calculate (Newton's symbol 49 choose 6) that there are approximately $1.4×10^7$ possible sets to choose, and so, the probability of winning is about $7×10^{-8}$. My question, however, is this: is there a difference in probability of winning between choosing numbers randomly, and in some very specific order like $1,2,3,4,5,6$?

Comment: Assuming that each number from $1$ to $49$ is chosen with equal probability, any combination of $6$ numbers is equally likely.  But assuming the prize pool is based on a parimutuel model, the more popular combinations have a lower expected value *because* they are more popular, so they will win less when they do win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lottery is fair then any set of six numbers is equally likely to be the winner, even if some sets look less random than others. That's the definition of "fair". By analogy, if you flip a fair coin $10$ times then each of the $1024$ possible sequences of heads and tails is equally probable. You are just as likely to see `HTTHTTHHTT` as `HHHHHHHHHH` or `HTHTHTHTHT`.

That said, many people share your perception that the set $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is somehow not a winner chosen at random. There are surely at least $150$ sets that seem special: those with consecutive numbers, or like $2,4,6,8, 10, 12$,   or are all prime, or have the same tens digit or units digit. Given that, the chance that the winning sequence will be suspect is something like $150 \times 7 \times 10^{-8}$ which is about $1$ in $100,000$. There are many lotteries like the one where you live, (many run daily)  so from time to time you will see claims that some particular lottery must be rigged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!